# How to connect aws VPC's on two regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a requirement to host MySQL RDS on Sydney region and connect to it from Singapore region. RDS is hosted on VPC which is located on Sydney region. Connect to a DB over the internet is too slow.

Comment: You can set a tunnel between the two regions.

Comment: did you meant ipsec tunnel. Does it speed up the connection between two VPC's.

Comment: http://fortycloud.com/interconnecting-two-aws-vpc-regions/

Comment: if "over the internet" is too slow, what kind of magical solution are you expecting to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon recently announced [inter-region VPC peering](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/Welcome.html). You can now connect VPCs without having to create any instances.

Answer (score 1):

Some options for connecting two Amazon VPCs that are located in different regions are:

**A software VPN connection between the two regions:**

[image: Software VPN connection between two regions]

**Software-to-Hardware VPN connection** taking advantage of a Virtual Gateway on one end:

[image: Software-to-Hardware VPN connection]

They both rely on running across the Internet. The only way to avoid the Internet would be to run across **Direct Connect** fibre links, hubbing back to your own data centre:

[image: Direct Connect hubs]

See:

- Whitepaper: [Amazon VPC Network Connectivity Options](https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/amazon-vpc-connectivity-options/)
- Article: [Connecting Multiple VPCs with EC2 Instances (IPSec)](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5472675506466066)

Comment: Thank @john.Appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set up a VPN connection by using 2 EC2 with StrongSwan connected to each other. Then you can use private addresses to access the other VPC. I had to do the same some time back. Hope this helps:

https://notes.ayushsharma.in/2017/02/connecting-vpcs-in-2-aws-regions-site-to-site-vpn